# Efficient method to calculate passes (rises and sets) for satellites

Tags: roots, problem-solving

There is a function describing the characterisic elevation of ISS seen from an observers horizon. Calculating of an elevation at one time is pretty expensive. So I wanna try to avoid naive iterating over time.
I look for a efficient way to get the zero crossings which corresponds to rise and set.

[image: function]

Which method could I take to calculate the zero crossings from now to the future (positive direction). For example a task would be: What are the next three rises, transits and sets from now on? 
Thanks.

Comment: "There is a function describing the characterisic elevation of ISS seen from an observers horizon." Well, can you tell us what that function is? Also, it looks like your graph does not have enough sampling: the peak at about 16:00:00 is underresolved.

Comment: @Rahul Thanks for your answer. Yes, the graph is just an example. I can get altitude and azimuth by [python-skyfield](https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/python-skyfield/blob/cfc56eb8967da7e87f6676d78133118e67b21631/skyfield/positionlib.py#L244). So I just use a library right now.